# Get the url of page

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I use this to navigate to a website

```
doc = web.Load("http://google.com/search?btnI=1&q=[my keyword]") //I'm Feeling Lucky
```

Then I need the url of navigated website... How can I get it?

Comment: You mean you need to know what search result the user clicked on?

Comment: This get the first result in google search (I'm feeling lucky) and navigate to that page... I don't know where he navigated

Comment: He's using the Google "I'm feeling lucky" feature, which automatically redirects you to the top search result. He wants to know what URI Google has automatically navigated to.

Comment: @JeffJohnson yeah exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `HtmlWeb.ResponseUri` property which gets the URI of the Internet resource that actually responded to the request.

An example - googling for "cookies":

```
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load("http://google.com/search?btnI=1&q=cookies");
var responseUrl = web.ResponseUri;
```

gets the `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the url of current browser by :

```
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```

Comment: I using htmlagilitypack... i don't have browser

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Sam1 might have given you the right answer (I have no real experience with the HTML Agility Pack) for a one or two instance endeavor.

That being said, if you intend to make a lot of calls to Google using `keywords` so that you can retrieve the top result (i.e. the "I'm Feeling Lucky" result), then I would highly suggest you use Google's Custom Search API (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview).

It would use MUCH less bandwidth if you are pulling JSON results using this API.

Usage of the API only allows for 100 free queries per day. This might fall within your application requirements, but it also might not. If you have the means, I would suggest supporting Google by paying if you intend to make thousands of queries.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to note here. First - using "http://google.com" in the above URL without the "www" forces a 301 redirect to "http://www.google.com" so you should include the www to keep things simple.

The second is that opening the URL (with the www) performs a 302 redirect. The destination is inside the response headers. So if you can catch that 302 response, you can get the URL Google will send you to, before it sends you there.

Here are the response and request headers for the first request, in which Google performs a 301 redirect to the www domain.

**Response Headers**
Cache-Control   public, max-age=2592000
Content-Length  244
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date    Mon, 18 Feb 2013 14:14:40 GMT
Expires Wed, 20 Mar 2013 14:14:40 GMT
Location    http://www.google.com/search?btnI=1&q=html5
Server  gws
X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection    1; mode=block

**Request Headers**
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  PREF=ID=5d01155d00a8d706:U=49fab5927df1f8ad:FF=0:TM=1359732743:LM=1360874099:S=byw-1-fgfbcRWdPN; NID=67=NpFNjRkjTFtyrcYPE-pQeJiMFEgWMWdyVMVpbYATZySlsw63Hz4FCw2Tcr4tynhAhyq1vnuPqmdFBOC65Nd-048ZxrgP_HVtKbVCe7psi-G2aMvsOUbiBl1xYks2xK2K
DNT 1
Host    google.com
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0

And the response/request headers for the 302 that takes me to the destination page. You can see the destination URL is returned. I've bolded it in the copy.

**Response Headers**
Cache-Control   private
Content-Length  231
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date    Mon, 18 Feb 2013 14:14:41 GMT
Location    **http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5**
Server  gws
X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection    1; mode=block

**Request Headers**
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  PREF=ID=5d01155d00a8d706:U=49fab5927df1f8ad:FF=0:TM=1359732743:LM=1360874099:S=byw-1-fgfbcRWdPN; NID=67=NpFNjRkjTFtyrcYPE-pQeJiMFEgWMWdyVMVpbYATZySlsw63Hz4FCw2Tcr4tynhAhyq1vnuPqmdFBOC65Nd-048ZxrgP_HVtKbVCe7psi-G2aMvsOUbiBl1xYks2xK2K
DNT 1
Host    www.google.com
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0